# Chef Foodcritic rule not catching attribute strings

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, chef-infra

I have written a foodcritic rule to catch any attempt to write to a blacklist of directories/files under the /etc directory.

When blacklisted paths are passed to resource declarations as strings in a recipe, the rule triggers, however when they are passed as attributes, the rule does not trigger:

```
@resources = [
'file',
'template',
'remote_file',
'remote_directory',
'directory'
]

@blacklist = [
'/etc/ssh/',
'/etc/init',
...
]

rule 'RULE001', 'do not manipulate /etc other than init/,init.d/ & default/' do
  tags %w(security)
  recipe do |ast|
    violations = []
    @resources.each do |resource_type|
      violations << find_resources(ast, type: resource_type).select do |resource|
        res_str = (resource_attribute(resource, 'path' || resource_name(resource)).to_s
        @blacklist.any? { |cmd| res_str.include? cmd }
      end
    end
    violations.flatten
  end
end
```

Testing this using the below, the literal strings are caught, however when passed as attributes they are passed. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

attributes/default.rb:

```
default['testbook']['etc-test'] = '/etc/ssh/test.conf'
default['testbook']['etc-dir-test'] = 'etc/ssh/somedir/'
```

recipes/default.rb:

```
#template '/etc/ssh/test.conf' do <-- caught
template node['testbook']['etc-test'] do #<-- not caught
  source 'test.conf'
  owner 'nobody'
  group 'nobody'
  mode '0644'
  action :create
end

#directory '/etc/ssh/somedir' do <-- caught
directory node['testbook']['etc-dir-test'] do <-- not caught
  action :create
end
```

Comment: On reflection, I think I need to check the contents of the attributes files for blacklisted paths as the attributes aren't resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this isn't something you can fully handle via static analysis. Foodcritic and tools like it can only handle things that are static in the code, anything that could vary at runtime won't be known.